# html5 drag and drop - unwanted javascript looping

Tags: javascript, html, drag

I'm creating a schedule table in html and javascript.  An unstyled fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/tobyla/6xa225gx/

The user is able to drag workers to different roles within the same 'Day' column. Part of the requirement is that the user can drag absent workers into the absentee column, where they can be displayed. (there can be more than one for any given day).

The problem is that for each additional worker added to the column, the javascript loops more and more times, adding the new names multiple times.

the problem seems to be rooted around this code:

```
else if (draggedItem != this && targetThisDay == thisDay && targetShiftPattern == "absentees") { //MH - swap if we're not dragging the item onto itself
    copy = "<tr>" + $(this).clone(true,true) + "</tr>";
    $(this).after($(draggedItem).clone(true,true));
    $(draggedItem).replaceWith('<td class="dnd" draggable="true"  data-dayoftheweek="monday" data-skillSet="skill2"> </td>');
    $(draggedItem).on("drop", handleDrop);
    alert('absenteeism');                
    runIndex();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated- thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `runIndex()` re-selects the same elements and re-binds the same event handlers.

You only need to bind these events once.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6xa225gx/1/).

Comment: thanks for the quick response, but your fiddle runs into a similar problem i was having - i run runIndex again to allow the cells left empty by the move to absenteeism to be repopulated.  As it stands trying to drag valid replacements into these gaps doesn't work.

Comment: In that case you should seriously consider an event delegation solution vs. the direct binding you're doing now.